# issue with print message to console

Tags: flutter

so I typed this code few moths ago and haven't managed to fix it. its supposed to bring up an error message when an incorrect email/password is entered.. this code is supposed to show a message in the terminal but it doesn't. I can't move to the next step if this doesn't work. I don't know what went wrong, I copied the tutorial.

`````
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('no user found with that enail');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('wrong password');
      }
    }````


tried rewriting, tried to skip this step but still didn't work
`````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seeing what the `e.code` value is? Maybe it has changed over time

Answer (score 0):

may another `object` is thrown not of type `FirebaseAuthException`, to figure the problem out.

**Try to print the stack trace of that exception**
also you may check other possible error codes

**invalid-email**: Thrown if the email address is not valid.

**user-disabled**: Thrown if the user corresponding to the given email has been disabled.

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailController.text,
    password: passwordController.text,
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('no user found with that enail');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('wrong password');
  }
   else if (e.code == 'invalid-email'){
    print('invalid-email');
  }
   else{ 
    print('user may be disaled');
  }

}
catch(e, st){
  print('thrown:  $e , stackTrace: $st');
 }
```

Hope it helps you.